# How to update algorithm to cryptonight v1

Tags: algorithm

I just tried to make a coin with source: https://github.com/seredat/karbowanec
and it works perfectly, then how do I update the algorithm of the code to make it Cryptonight v1?
is there any reference I can read?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update `src/crypto/slow-hash.c`. Compare it to Monero's latest version to see the changes.

Comment: whether replaced everything? or just a few lines?

Comment: Compare the changes

Comment: i just try, and get error

Comment: This is not the right forum for people to help you debug your fork coin code. Nor is posting an error log as an "answer".